# Get value directly or via method in Scala?

Tags: scala

One is able to define methods without paranthesis if they have no arguments. A special use-case is to use this to get values. Should I do this, or rather directly get the value?

So

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
  def re = real
  def im = imaginary
  override def toString() =
    "" + re + (if (im < 0) "" else "+") + im + "i"
}
```

or

```
class Complex(real: Double, imaginary: Double) {
  val re = real
  val im = imaginary
  override def toString() =
    "" + re + (if (im < 0) "" else "+") + im + "i"
}
```

Comment: Why have these defs or vals separate from the constructor args at all? Why not just `class Complex(val re: Double, val im: Double) { override def toString() = ... }`

Comment: @Jesper: Frankly, I am not sure: I am coming from http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html

Comment: Ok, that tutorial doesn't show that feature of Scala. If you put `val` in front of the constructor args, you get effectively the same thing as your second example.

Answer (score 2):

You can put `val` in front of the constructor arguments to make it a bit shorter, which is effectively the same as your second piece of code:

```
class Complex(val re: Double, val im: Double) {
  override def toString() = "" + re + (if (im < 0) "" else "+") + im + "i"
}
```

Note that `def` defines a **method**, while `val` defines a final member variable. Since the return value of these two methods is fixed, there's not really a reason to make them methods. So, in this case, use `val` instead of `def`.

Comment: "there's not really a reason to make them methods", unless you want to override them with `def`s in a subclass

Comment: @VictorMoroz Yes, but in this specific case with a class `Complex` that represents complex numbers that seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Even better: make it a **case** class:

```
case class Complex(re: Double, im: Double) {
   override def toString() = "%f%+fi".format(re,im)
}
```

This gives you `re` and `im` as members, plus some additional perks, such as `copy`:

```
val a = Complex(1,2)
val realA = a.copy(im = 0)
```

and `unapply`:

```
def isImaginary(a: Complex) = a match {
   case Complex(0, _) => true
   case _ => false
}

def abs(a: Complex) = a match {
   case Complex(re, im) => re*re + im*im
}
```

and also `equals`, `hashCode`, etc.

Comment: One last thing: `case class`es already provide an implementation of `toString`, which would render, for example, to something like `"Complex(4.2, 4.7)"`. Furthermore, if you want to override the `toString` method you can also override it with a `val` instead of a `def` so that its value is not recomputed each time you ask for it (you may want to this if you happen to have individual instances of your class rendered as a string multiple times throughout the code - for logging purposes, for example).